# How to find .pyc files with python version > 3.0 for OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I learned today that

> In Python < 3.2, the .pyc files are placed in the same directory as the .py file.
>
> In Python > 3.2, the compiled files are placed in a **pycache** subdirectory, and are named differently depending on which Python interpreter created them.

When I wanted to learn how any function works in Python 2, I would just open the .py file of that module and learn from the code of the function. But now in Python 3, I cannot find .py find and also I cannot decompile the Python37__pycache__\code.cpython-37.pyc file. So if I want the code of a function from a module, how can I get it?

Just for context, now I want to learn how method traingleList() works of class Subdiv2D of module cv2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you mentioned which function you're talking about.

OpenCV-Python is mostly just a big ol' binary blob, so you won't be able to find a .py file or .pyc file of it.

```
$ ls -la site-packages/cv2/
    1824 Mar 18 11:09 .dylibs
     233 Mar 18 11:09 __init__.py
80005472 Mar 18 11:09 cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
     672 Mar 18 11:09 data
```

Furthermore, based on [the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/ca23c0e630ba9c4fc147c4913d6238f5de3bbcd9/modules/python/src2) it looks like it's autogenerated from the C++ version, with some conversion additions.

For your particular question, though, the C++ source for `getTriangleList` is [over here if you want to take a look](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ca23c0e630ba9c4fc147c4913d6238f5de3bbcd9/modules/imgproc/src/subdivision2d.cpp#L756-L786).